# .htaccess redirection from old domain to new domain

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following code in my .htaccess file that is located in the root folder but it is not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Both the domains are `https` if that makes a difference. Sorry am new to this.

Comment: Are both host names resolved to the same IP address of that http server? And does that server respond to both host names? How did you enable the interpretation of distributed configuration files? What does your http server's error log file reveal?

Comment: @arkascha No both domains are on different hosts. Both are my domains and my hosting accounts. Basically I created a new version of the site on a new domain and a new host and simply want to redirect visitors to my old site/domain to my new one.

Comment: So I assume you implemented this rule on the server hosting the _old_ domain? OK, fine. What about the rest of my questions?